# Use command expansion as argument of `for` loop or initializing an array

Tags: bash, shell

I met a problem with using a function's output (strings contain spaces) in `for` loop and array initialization.
I wonder why the expressions below has different behavior.

It performs right when normal strings passed in `for in` structure.

```
$ for str in 'a b' 'c d'; do echo $str; done
a b
c d
```

But when I use output of a function, things are different.

```
foo ()
{
    echo "'a b' 'c d'"
}
$ for str in $(foo); do echo $str; done
'a
b'
'c
d'
```

Similar situation happens on initializing an array too:

```
$ strs=('a b' 'c d')
$ echo "${strs[@]}"
a b c d
$ echo "${strs[0]}"
a b
```

But

```
$ strs=( $(foo) )
$ echo "${strs[@]}"
'a b' 'c d'
$ echo "${strs[0]}"
'a
```

Use output of a function, which has same value of the constants, but produces different results. Why this would happen? What's the internal mechanism behind it.

### Most important, how can I use output of a function gain same result of using constants.

Do have a look at the link in the comment of this question, it contains more than just this question, that helps very much.

Comment: The problem is that the quotes output by the command substitution are literal quotes, not syntactic quotes. They do not escape the whitespace during word-splitting. What you want simply isn't possible without using `eval`, which isn't recommended unless you have complete control over the output of `foo`.

Comment: Also, see [Bash FAQ 001](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) regarding the use of a `for` loop to iterate over the output of a command. (TL;DR don't. use a `while` loop that calls `read` instead.)

Comment: @chepner thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A workaround (assuming none of your array elements can contain newlines) is to simply output unquoted lines of text, and use `readarray` to populate your array.

```
foo () {
    echo 'a b'
    echo 'c d'
}

readarray -t strs < <(foo)
for str in "${strs[@]}"; do
    echo "$str"
done
```

Comment: Hey, thank you very much for your excellent answer. Is it possible to get avoid usage of array? thanks

Comment: For some reason I need this to work on an Android device too, and it doesn't use bash so `readarray` is not supported.

Comment: @sparkecho: the tags you use on a question are important. If you tag a question as [tag:bash], it is assumed that you are looking for a bash solution. If you are using a different shell, use the tag for that shell (or use [tag:shell] for generic solutions). Saying "oh but I didn't want a bash solution" after asking for a [tag:bash] solution is not good etiquette.

Comment: @rici thanks for your warnning. But actually this script should run both on bash and sh. I'm gonna delete the bash tag.

Comment: If you are restricting yourself to POSIX `sh`, you are really better off switching to a different language altogether, one with proper data structures.

Comment: @sparkecho: With a few exceptions, scripts which work with POSIX shells will also work with bash, and most people answering generic [tag:shell] questions will avoid the few constructs in which bash is not POSIX-compliant.

Answer (score 1):

this can be done with a while loop without storing command output in an array

```
foo() {
    echo 'a b'
    echo 'c d'
}

foo | while read; do
    echo "$REPLY"
done
```

tested on both bash 4.4.23 and adb shell